# SQL Server - MySQL migration error: incorrect string value: '\xF4\x80\x82\x83...'

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I am new to MySQL and migrating a client's MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a Windows Server 2008 R2 to MySql Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL community Server - GPL) on a Windows 2016 Server using the MySql Workbench 8.0 migration tool, copying the data using the Online copy of table data to target RDBMS option.

I get  warnings on all the SQL Server varchar and ntext columns that "Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS migrated to utf8_general_ci", but this only seems to be a problem with the table with two ntext columns. That table fails to migrate data with the "incorrect string value: '\xF4\x80\x82\x83...'" error.

Though I'm a little fuzzy on character sets and collations, my scouring of the internet indicates that the problem is MySQL's utf8 only allows 3 bytes and I need to move this data under utf8mb4 which allows for 4 bytes.
I changed the my.ini file like this:

```
[client]

default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This results in the following variable values for character_set_* being (mostly) utf8mb4 except for the character_set_system, which remains utf8, and the character_set_filesystem being binary. The collation variables being utf8mb4_unicode_ci:
[Character set and collation variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc6bC.jpg)

It seems like the migration tool is ignoring this? Does anyone know how I can get this data moved intact, preferably with the easy to use migration tool? (Bearing in mind that my inexperience in this environment means I need pretty explicit help). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What the migration tools are you use?

In the last time I also have same problem but with AWS DMS. It come from the Emoji character. If you have the same situation like me you can use "Extra connection attributes" to replace the Emoji character at source EndPoint.

Example:
parallelLoadThreads=1;ReplaceChars=F09F988A,3F,F09F9982,3F,F09F8CBB,3F,F09FA681,3F,F09F918C,3F,F09F9882E298,3F

For another way, you can remove the emoji character before save to database. It's not friendly with Database Migration Tools.